# Proof of Metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are metrics on $M$. Prove that $p=\max\{p_1,p_2\}$ is a metric on $M$.

I am supposed to define $p_2$ and $p_3$ as:
\begin{gather*}p_1=\sup(x,y),\\
p_2=\sup(a,b).\end{gather*}
Then $p_2=\sup(\sup(x,y),\sup(a,b))$?

So I know I have to satisfy these 3 conditions:

- $p(x,y)\ge0$ and $p(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$
- $p(x,y)=p(y,x)$
- $p(x,z)\le p(x,y)+p(y,z)$

But I am completely lost.  I do not have any clue how to work this out.

Comment: $p_1$ is a metric on $M$, so for any $x,y\in M$, $p_1(x,y)$ is a nonnegative real number and $p_1$ satisfies the $3$ conditions you listed. $p_2$ is another metric. You are not asked to define $p_1$ and $p_2$ in any way, they are already given to you. What you are doing is defining a new function $p:M\times M\to[0,\infty)$, by setting $$p(x,y)=\max\{p_1(x,y),p_2(x,y)\}$$ for any $x,y\in M$. What you need to do is to show that this function $p$ is also a metric, that is, it satisfies the $3$ conditions. The proof of this must somehow use that the $3$ conditions are satisfied by $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Comment: By $\sup(x,y)$ do you mean $\max\{x,y\}$?

Answer (score 2):

The function $p$ is a metric independently of the definition of $p_1$ and $p_2$, so long as they are metrics.

In what follows, $x,y,z\in M$.

1. Since $p_1(x,y)\ge0$ and $p_2(x,y)\ge0$, so $p(x,y)=\max\{p_1(x,y),p_2(x,y)\}\ge0$ for obvious reasons
2. Suppose $p(x,y)=0$; then $\max\{p_1(x,y),p_2(x,y)\}=0$, which implies …
3. $p(x,y)=\max\{p_1(x,y),p_2(x,y)\}=\max\{p_1(y,x),p_2(y,x)\}$, so …
4. Triangle inequality: this is the most difficult, but not so much.

Start with $p(x,z)=\max\{p_1(x,z),p_2(x,z)\}$. Since $p_1$ and $p_2$ are metrics, you can say that
\begin{gather}
p_1(x,z)\le p_1(x,y)+p_1(y,z)\\
p_2(x,z)\le p_2(x,y)+p_2(y,z)
\end{gather}
Therefore
$$
\max\{p_1(x,z),p_2(x,z)\}\le
\max\{p_1(x,y)+p_1(y,z),p_2(x,y)+p_2(y,z)\}
$$
Can you show that
$$
\max\{p_1(x,y)+p_1(y,z),p_2(x,y)+p_2(y,z)\}\le
\max\{p_1(x,y),p_2(x,y)\}+\max\{p_1(y,z),p_2(y,z)\}
$$
by carefully comparing terms?